Check if textbox exist in table cell or not
Here is my code:


var result = '';
var rows = $("#table_wf tbody tr input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i]
    result += rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
    var v = rows[i].cells.find("td input[type=text]");
    if (rows[i].cells.find("input[type=text]").length) {
    } 
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_wf">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Some Dummy Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input id="chk_001" type="checkbox" selected></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>Some Dummy Text</td>
        <td><input id="text_002" type="text" value="22"/></td>
        <td><input id="chk_002" type="checkbox" selected/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



1st column contain codes like A,B,C
2nd column contain some dummy text
3rd column might contain a input box or might not, here 1st row does not have text box, 2nd row does
4th and last column contain a checkbox
now on change of any checkbox what I want is
text from column 1 + text from column 3 text box if present
I am able to get value from first <td> tag of row but not able to check if that row contain text box in 3rd <td> tag and if does, retrieve it's value
if (rows[i].cells.find("input[type=text]").length) {}

This is found on a post but it says that find rows[i].cells.find is not a function.
Maybe .find is not available on cells.
Anyway to accomplish this ?
value should be A (1st row), B22 (from 2nd row)
One comment suggested that rows[i].cells.find("td input[type=text]") means that finding a td within td collection because rows[i].cells return list of td, so I changed it to
rows[i].find("td input[type=text]").length

But error is still "rows[i].find is not a function"


"One comment" - the comment was removed as you mentioned find gave an error - you could do $(rows[i]).find... but seems overkill to keep switch between jquery and nodes like that - if using jquery, stick with jquery

Ok , so what should I use from jquery here , I am a c# developer, not much into node or jquery, Pardon my knowledge

No worries - was creating an answer for you, hence the deleted comments

Your requirement is exactly what .map was designed for.
Keeping with jquery one liner:
$("#table_wf tbody tr td :checked")
    .closest('tr')
    .map((i, e) => 
        $(e).find("td").eq(0).text() + ($(e).find("input[type='text']").val() || "")
    ).toArray();

Breakdown:

selector gets all the ticked checkboxes
gets all the rows for those checkboxes
loops through the rows
gets the first cell using .find("td").eq(0) and returns its text
gets the first textbox and returns its value - .val() will give the value of the first found
|| "" converts undefined to empty string
.toArray() converts the jquery .map response to a basic array
then you can .join(" ") if you want as a single string or use the array

Snippet


$("#table_wf :checkbox").click(() => {
  var result = $("#table_wf tbody tr td :checked").closest('tr').map((i, e) => $(e).find("td").eq(0).text() + ($(e).find("input[type='text']").val() || "")).toArray();
  
  console.log(result.join(" "))
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table_wf">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Some Dummy Text</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input id="chk_001" type="checkbox" selected></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Some Dummy Text</td>
      <td><input id="text_002" type="text" value="22" /></td>
      <td><input id="chk_002" type="checkbox" selected checked /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Amazing , minimum code with really good explanation of each step. Thanks

if first  is set as display:none, will it pick value from hidden cell ?

The display value has no impact based on this code (so yes).  If you want to ignore a cell, you could use $("td:not(:hidden)".   You might prefer an alternative approach - give all the cells in your first column a class (not an id) and then you can pick that with td.key (eg if class='key') and it won't matter what the position is.  Another alternative for "hidden" values is to use data- on the tr, eg data-key='A'.  It's unclear if you want to pick from the first column or want to ignore the first column if it's hidden (ie pick from the second)

You can loop through the cells using .eq(index) to access the cell at a specific index within a row.
Demo:


var result = '';
var rows = $("#table_wf tbody tr input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('tr');
rows.each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    result += row.find('td:first').text(); //first column text
    var textbox = row.find('td:eq(2) input[type="text"]');
    if (textbox.length) {
        result += textbox.val(); //value of the text box if present
    }
    result += '\n'; //add a newline for each row
});
console.log(result);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_wf">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Some Dummy Text</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input id="chk_001" type="checkbox" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Some Dummy Text</td>
      <td><input id="text_002" type="text" value="22"/></td>
      <td><input id="chk_002" type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




.find() is a jQuery method that is used to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and cannot be directly applied to rows[i].cells, which is a collection of DOM elements, not jQuery objects.
wrap the elements you're working with in jQuery
Also, the selected attribute should be checked


var result = '';

// Attach a change event listener to checkboxes in the table
$("#table_wf tbody tr input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    result = ''; // Reset result on change
    var rows = $("#table_wf tbody tr input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('tr');
    
    rows.each(function() {
        var row = $(this); // Wrap the row with jQuery
        var code = row.find('td:eq(0)').text(); // Get the text from the first column
        var textBox = row.find('td:eq(2) input[type="text"]'); // Find the input box in the third column
        var textBoxValue = textBox.val() ? textBox.val() : ''; // Get the value if the input box exists
        
        result += code + textBoxValue + ' '; // Concatenate the code and textBoxValue
    });

    console.log(result.trim());
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table_wf">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>Some Dummy Text</td>
<td></td>
<td><input id="chk_001" type="checkbox" selected></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td>Some Dummy Text</td>
<td><input id="text_002" type="text" value="22"/></td>
<td><input id="chk_002" type="checkbox" selected/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>




Firstly, I change selected to checked in the HTML, at least for the example. Didn't take in count possible user input.
find is a JQuery method, not a basic dom one. By only using JQuery method like find("td:first") and getting it from row and not cell, it works fine:


var result = '';
var rows = $("#table_wf tbody tr input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('tr');
rows.each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var firstCell = row.find("td:first");
    result += firstCell.html();
    var v = row.find("td input[type=text]"); // search td from row, so tr
    if (row.find("input[type=text]").length) {
      console.log("founded");
    }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_wf">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Some Dummy Text</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input id="chk_001" type="checkbox" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Some Dummy Text</td>
      <td><input id="text_002" type="text" value="22"/></td>
      <td><input id="chk_002" type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



